# Using Boost's pdf function

Tags: c++, boost

Silly question but I'm spending too much time looking for answers on the web with no success.
I have a boost::random::gamma_distribution object and a float value for which I would like to compute the pdf.

Which Boost modules exactly should I inlude and how to I call the function that computes a pdf for gamma?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have peeked at `random/gamma_distribution.hpp` and there isn't a method to return a pdf, so an instance of gamma_distribution won't help you. However, [boost::math::gamma_distribution](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/gamma_dist.html) provides implementation notes and a formula (the table at the bottom) to define a pdf using a library function `gamma_p_derivative`.

Now you can put together a pdf function yourself:

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp>

// Makes sense for k, theta, x greater than 0.
double gamma_pdf(double k, double theta, double x) {
    return boost::math::gamma_p_derivative(k, x / theta) / theta;
}
```

And that's basically it. Since `gamma.hpp` contains the required definitions you don't have to link any additional libraries during compilation.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [`pdf`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/nmp.html#math.dist.pdf) non-member function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/math/distributions/gamma.hpp>

int main() {
    double shape = 2;
    double scale = 1;
    boost::math::gamma_distribution<double> d(shape, scale);
    std::cout << pdf(d, .5) << std::endl;
}
```